# What is error: expected ')' before ';' token|

Tags: c, syntax-error

> I'm doing a small starter project for my school,and im kinda new to all the programing,now when i try to build my program it says that i need **")" before ";" in line 21**
>   and its asking for **"";" before the "}" in line 22"** and i have checked and there is a ";" before "}" but looks like my codeblocks is not recognizing it,or its just me being blind or me without a brain.
>   Thanks for looking at my question.

actual error code

> 21|error: expected ')' before ';' token
>   22|error: expected ';' before '}' token

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()

{
  int f,x;

  printf("Type in values of x: ");

  scanf("%d",&x);

  if (x <= 1)

  {(f = -2 * x);
      printf("%d",f);}

  else
      printf("Its not possible to do this function");


 if (1 < x < 5)

 {(f = sqrt(pow(x, 3)-(2*x));
        printf("%d",f);}

 else
    printf("Its not possible to do this function");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format the code so it's readable, and post the full error.\

Comment: The `(` in `(f =` looks suspicious though. I don't see that being closed.

Comment: `(f = sqrt(pow(x, 3)-(2*x));` has 4 `(` but only 3 `)`. Also `if (1 < x < 5)` doesn't do what you want it to do. Try `if (1 < x && x < 5)`.

Comment: You might want to look at coding styles; eg, https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/process/coding-style.html or any other that suits you. This probably would have helped with your error.

Answer (score 2):

Clang to the rescue:

```
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
   (f = sqrt(pow(x, 3) - (2 * x));
                                 ^
```

You are missing a closing `)`. By the way that pair of braces is not needed there at all:

```
 if (x > 1 && x < 5) // <-- BTW, the corrected condition
 {
     f = sqrt(pow(x, 3)-(2*x));
     printf("%d",f);
 }
 else
 { // <-- better to use braces symmetrically in if-else
    printf("Its not possible to do this function");
 }
```